# Parse table in HTML Agility Pack for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, html-parsing

I have following HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="8" cellpadding="6" border="1" style="color: Black; background-color: LightGoldenrodYellow;
    width: 60%;" id="GridView2" rules="all">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="color: White; background-color: #CF4B0A; font-weight: bold;">
            <th align="center" scope="col">
                Booked At
            </th>
            <th align="center" scope="col">
                Booked On
            </th>
            <th align="center" scope="col">
                Delivered At
            </th>
            <th align="center" scope="col">
                Delivered On
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Details
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left" style="color: #333333; background-color: #FFFBA1; font-family: Arial;
            font-size: Small;">
            <td align="center">
                Not Available
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                Not Available
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                DATA
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                12/01/2012
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView2$ctl02$LinkButton1','')" id="GridView2_ctl02_LinkButton1">
                    Details</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to parse the above table using HTML Agility pack. I'm using the HAP solution for WP7, downloaded from Codeplex. 
Any quick help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's not enough information to be able to help you with this.  For example, what are you trying to pull out of the HTML?  What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

To parse the HTML, use HAP's HtmlDocument.LoadHtml() function and pass it the actual string. That will give you a DOM with all the HTML objects in it.